# How to set z-index on a control within AbsoluteLayout in xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an AbsoluteLayout on a view in my Xamarin.Forms app, with 3 buttons in it. After another control is added programmatically, it covers the buttons. I cannot figure out how I can make the buttons to be always in front.

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="Container" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Button
            Style="{StaticResource CallButtonStyle}"      
             ...                
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".85,.02" 
            Text="{Binding CameraSwitchIcon}" />

        <Button
            ...
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".15,.95,80,80"
            Text="{Binding VideoToggleIcon}" />

        <Button
            ...
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".85,.95,80,80"
            Text="{Binding AudioToggleIcon}" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: you can use RaiseChild() and LowerChild() to change the z-order of an element

Comment: @Jason I will try it and let you know. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jason Hmm, I did it like this: Container.RaiseChild(SwitchCameraButton);

But it did not work. Am I missing something? SwitchCameraButton is x:Name of the button.

Comment: are you doing it on the UI thread?

Comment: @Jason I am doing this in an event handler.

Comment: public void SetLocalViewHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _layoutManager.SetLocalView(_pageModel.VideoChatLocalView);
            Container.RaiseChild(SwitchCameraButton);
        }

Comment: that's not really enough context to be helpful.  You can try using MainThread to force RaiseChild to the UI thread.

Comment: @Jason I found my problem, and now it works! Please make it your Answer, so I could mark it as such. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all XF Layouts have `RaiseChild()` and `LowerChild()` methods you can use to adjust the Z index